Is it illegal to save "View Once" media sent on Whatsapp?
It has been found that the "View Once" feature provided by Whatsapp is implemented simply with a flag, and can be trivially bypassed to allow the media to be saved and viewed multiple times.  One can get an Android client/Chrome extension to do this, though they may be a greater security risk to the installer than anyone who sends them data.  This has always been obviously possible via an external camera.
Is bypassing the Whatsapp "View Once" feature breaking any laws?  Does it matter how you do it, in software or with a camera?

What country's laws?

@MichaelHarvey Any jurisdiction would be interesting.  The rule is not to mark it as such anymore

Are you specifically interested in laws that might be broken, as opposed to whether it breach the terms of a contract/EULA that might exist between the person doing this and WhatsApp?

@TripeHound Yes, I am interested in laws that might be broken.

It sounds to me like a copyright violation. If the sender owns the copyright (unless Whatsapp's terms say that the copyright is transferred to Whatsapp when you use it), they're only giving you permission to view it once, not to make a permanent copy.
In the US, anyone making an extension with the express purpose of getting around this setting might also be in violation of the DMCA. This prohibits creating and distributing tools whose purpose is to violate copy protections.
There may be some jurisdictions that excempt private copies from copyright protection like this (e.g. France), in which case this doesn't apply.

The first part of your answer is also specific to the US. For instance, in France, private copies are an exemption to copyright (and the OP’s scenario would qualify, assuming they do not show the screenshot to other people).

I've updated the answer to say that it depends on the jurisdiction.

This is assuming that the sender has a claim to the copyright in the first place which might not be true b

@JoeW If the sender was violating copyright when sending, that's a totally separate issue. The recipient still hasn't been given permission by the copyright owner to make a permanent copy. Although if the image was public domain, then none of this is a copyright issue.

You can send images even if you don’t hold the copyright and not be infringing on copyright. It isn’t a good leap in logic to jump to copyright infringement b

Only if you've been given permission by the copyright holder. And that permission isn't usually transitive.

But that is a different issue and it doesn’t change the fact that sending an image over chat suggest that you have copyright over it. There are plenty of images that are perfectly legal to share even though you don’t own the copyright.

@JoeW My answer says nothing about the sender's right to send the image. The question is about the receiver's rights.

If you are saying it isn’t the sender’s rights then the copyright infringement has nothing to do with the view once flag which means you are not answering the question.

I changed the answer to be conditional: If the sender owns the copyright.

It's a breach of contract
The Whatsapp Terms of Service say:

Harm To WhatsApp Or Our Users. You must not (or assist others to) directly, indirectly, through automated or other means, access, use, copy, adapt, modify, prepare derivative works based upon, distribute, license, sublicense, transfer, display, perform, or otherwise exploit our Services in impermissible or unauthorized manners, or in ways that burden, impair, or harm us, our Services, systems, our users, or others ...

Disclosing the image may be the tort of breach of confidence
Although that will be highly fact dependent.
Copyright
As @Barmar says, taking the screenshot may be copyright infringement.
